# How to replace a column string value if it is a substring of another column

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

How to replace a part string value of a column using another column.

My DataSet here is :

```
ID          Product Name                            Size ID    Size Name
1   24 Mantra Ancient Grains Foxtail Millet 500 gm      1       500 gm
2   24 Mantra Ancient Grains Little Millet 500 gm       2       500 gm
3   24 Mantra Naturals Almonds 100 gm                   3       100 gm
4   24 Mantra Naturals Kismis 100 gm                    4       100 gm
5   24 Mantra Organic Ajwain 100 gm                     5       100 gm
6   24 Mantra Organic Apple Blast Drink 250 ml          6       250 ml
7   24 Mantra Organic Apple Juice 1 Ltr Tetra Pack      7       1000 ml
8   24 Mantra Organic Apple Juice 200 ml                8       200 ml
9   24 Mantra Organic Assam Tea 100 gm                  9       100 gm
```

Requirement here is the `Product Name` column value is `24 Mantra Ancient Grains Foxtail Millet 500 gm` and the `Size Name` column has `500 Gm`.  In this case my output will be `24 Mantra Ancient Grains Foxtail Millet`.
If the `Size Name` contains in the `Product Name` string remove the size name word ignoring the case else no need to take any action.

Comment: Perhaps you could post an example of any code you have tried and an example of what your ideal output should look like so people can help you better. SO is not a code writing website.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Pandas removing substring using another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34773317/python-pandas-removing-substring-using-another-column)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Pandas: Check if string in one column is contained in string of another column in the same row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43855685/python-pandas-check-if-string-in-one-column-is-contained-in-string-of-another-c)

Comment: remove the Size Name and replace with None?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `apply()` and `replace()`:

```
df['Product Name'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Product Name'].replace(x['Size Name'], '').strip(), axis=1)
```

Yields:

```
   ID                                    Product Name  Size ID Size Name
0   1         24 Mantra Ancient Grains Foxtail Millet        1    500 gm
1   2          24 Mantra Ancient Grains Little Millet        2    500 gm
2   3                      24 Mantra Naturals Almonds        3    100 gm
3   4                       24 Mantra Naturals Kismis        4    100 gm
4   5                        24 Mantra Organic Ajwain        5    100 gm
5   6             24 Mantra Organic Apple Blast Drink        6    250 ml
6   7  24 Mantra Organic Apple Juice 1 Ltr Tetra Pack        7   1000 ml
7   8                   24 Mantra Organic Apple Juice        8    200 ml
8   9                     24 Mantra Organic Assam Tea        9    100 gm
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to replace the Size Name values with None if they are substrings of Product Name

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
            'Product Name' : ['24 Mantra Ancient Grains Foxtail Millet 500 gm', '24 Mantra Ancient Grains Little Millet 500 gm ', '24 Mantra Naturals Kismis 100 gm'], 
            'Size ID' : [1, 2, 3],
            'Size Name': ['500 gm', '500 gm', '200 gm']
        })

df['same']= df.apply(lambda x: x['Size Name'] in x['Product Name'], axis = 1)
df['Size Name'] = np.where(df['same'], None, df['Size Name'])
df.drop(columns=['same'], inplace = True)
df

  Product Name                                Size ID      Size Name
0   24 Mantra Ancient Grains Foxtail Millet 500 gm  1              None
1   24 Mantra Ancient Grains Little Millet 500 gm   2              None
2   24 Mantra Naturals Kismis 100 gm                3              200 gm
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming,you the `size name` will always be the last column, here is what i think you need:

```
import re

data = '''ID          Product Name                            Size ID    Size Name
1   24 Mantra Ancient Grains Foxtail Millet 500 gm      1       500 gm
2   24 Mantra Ancient Grains Little Millet 500 gm       2       500 gm
3   24 Mantra Naturals Almonds 100 gm                   3       100 gm
4   24 Mantra Naturals Kismis 100 gm                    4       100 gm
5   24 Mantra Organic Ajwain 100 gm                     5       100 gm
6   24 Mantra Organic Apple Blast Drink 250 ml          6       250 ml
7   24 Mantra Organic Apple Juice 1 Ltr Tetra Pack      7       1000 ml
8   24 Mantra Organic Apple Juice 200 ml                8       200 ml
9   24 Mantra Organic Assam Tea 100 gm                  9       100 gm
'''
def cleaner(txt):
    data = txt
    temp = data.split('\n')
    products = temp[1:-1]
    fixed_products = [temp[0]]

    for p in products:
    res = re.search('(\d+\s\w*)$', p)
    try:
        match = res.group(0)
        ignore_from = len(match)
        found_at = p[:-ignore_from].find(match)
        if found_at > -1:#we found a duplicate
            fixed_product = p.replace(match,'',1)
            fixed_products.append(fixed_product)
    except:
        pass
    products = '\n'.join(fixed_products)
    return products

#Example
#cleaner(data)
```

[image: Here is the result]

Comment: This does not leverage pandas or dataframes at all.

Comment: @rahlf23, nope it doesn't..I'm simply trying to show him how to DIY, it's more understandable but if pd's dfs is what he is looking for then your solution and Mohit's solutions above should suffice