# Fast way to remove substring in a column using another column

Tags: python, pandas

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34773317/python-pandas-removing-substring-using-another-column) although I am trying to find a faster tool than pandas. Here is my starting table:

```
    col1        col2
0  ABCDE   [AB]B[CD]
1  BCDEA   [BC][CD]E
2  CDEAB  [CD][CD]EA
3  DEABC       [DE]A
4  EABCD       [DE]A
```

In case you want to reproduce it in python pandas, you can use this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['ABCDE', '[AB]B[CD]'],
                   ['BCDEA', '[BC][CD]E'],
                   ['CDEAB', '[CD][CD]EA'],
                   ['DEABC', '[DE]A'],
                   ['EABCD', '[DE]A']],
                  columns=['col1', 'col2'])
```

My goal is to subtract col2 from col1 considering:

a. col2 uses regex

b. In order to make any change, col1 should *start* with col2

Here is the expected output:

```
    col1        col2   col3
0  ABCDE   [AB]B[CD]     DE
1  BCDEA   [BC][CD]E  BCDEA
2  CDEAB  [CD][CD]EA      B
3  DEABC       [DE]A  DEABC
4  EABCD       [DE]A    BCD
```

I have found a solution with pandas, but a 2,000,000 line file makes the script quite slow. Here is the command:

`df['col3'] = df.col1.replace(df.col2[df.col2.notnull()], '', regex = True).str.lstrip()`

One solution is to split the large file into many and use different cpu to do the job, but I was wondering whether *awk*, *sed* or *perl* could do this more efficiently. Any idea?

Comment: The output doesn't match the provided regex, for instance `[CD]EAB` shouldn't remove anything given the start anchor constraint and the fact that `[CD]` matches only **one** of C or D.

Comment: @mozway wouldn't `[CD]EAB` match the ending `DEAB` in `CDEAB`? Your solution forces the pattern at the beginning of the strings, while the OP doesn't seem to care for that.

Comment: @QuangHoang OP specified "*In order to make any change, col1 should start with col2*", maybe I misunderstood what they meant

Comment: @mozway indeed I missed that part. Then the output doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Edit --- You're right @mozway I messed up my col3, I edited it the way I want it to.

Comment: @Sara thanks! then the "anchoring" alternative should be what you want

Comment: Are the row numbers part of your actual data file?

Comment: @Shawn it's the representation of a pandas (python) dataframe, likely not the raw input. I am not sure why there are so many tags here

Comment: @mozway But they say the data comes from a file. Seeing *that* would be useful, not some random python representation.

Comment: @Shawn I started trying to solve this using python, so mozway is right, the numbers are not the raw input, but it doesn't matter too much.  My goal is to make something quicker than my solution in python, so perl (or awk or sed) solutions are welcome (hence the tags). I am looking at your perl solution, thanks!

Comment: @Shawn yes of course (I imagine this could be CSV)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you need to loop here.

Your anchoring condition is unclear ("*In order to make any change, col1 should start with col2*", but this doesn't seem to match the output) so I'll provide both options:

##### anchoring to the start:

```
import re

df['col3'] = [re.sub(f'^{b}', '', a) for a,b in zip(df['col1'], df['col2'])]
```

output:

```
    col1        col2   col3
0  ABCDE   [AB]B[CD]     DE
1  BCDEA   [BC][CD]E  BCDEA
2  CDEAB  [CD][CD]EA      B
3  DEABC       [DE]A  DEABC
4  EABCD       [DE]A    BCD
```

##### no anchoring:

```
df['col3'] = [re.sub(f'{b}', '', a) for a,b in zip(df['col1'], df['col2'])]
```

output:

```
    col1        col2 col3
0  ABCDE   [AB]B[CD]   DE
1  BCDEA   [BC][CD]E   BA
2  CDEAB  [CD][CD]EA    B
3  DEABC       [DE]A  DBC
4  EABCD       [DE]A  BCD
```

Comment: I can't make it work and I am not sure why... f'^{b}' gives a  "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Comment: Which python version do you have? You can use `'^'+b` instead of `f'^{b}'`.

Comment: great, if you really need speed, still check the `awk` alternative on your raw data file (but you probably would need to tweak it) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using a `perl` one-liner (And assuming whitespace-separated columns):

```sh
$ perl -lane 'print join("\t", @F, $F[0] =~ s/^$F[1]//r)' input.txt
ABCDE   [AB]B[CD]       DE
BCDEA   [BC][CD]E       BCDEA
CDEAB   [CD][CD]EA      B
DEABC   [DE]A   DEABC
EABCD   [DE]A   BCD
```

Or `awk`:

```sh
$ awk '{ $3 = $1; sub("^" $2, "", $3); print }' OFS="\t" input.txt
ABCDE   [AB]B[CD]       DE
BCDEA   [BC][CD]E       BCDEA
CDEAB   [CD][CD]EA      B
DEABC   [DE]A   DEABC
EABCD   [DE]A   BCD
```

Comment: Great awk solution! It works as well as the python above and much faster. On my large file, it runs in 7s (vs 26s for python). Thanks!